# Text-align center not working on Windows Phone if image is rectangular

Tags: html, css, windows-phone-8

I am porting a cordova/phonegap app from android to WP8.

I cannot center my rectangular image while it is centered on android.

Here my HTML:

```
<div data-theme="" id="" class="logologin">
    <img src="../img/myImg.png" alt=""/>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.logologin {
    margin-top: 1px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

I tried with a square img and it is centered.

- How to fix it?

Comment: what do you mean, "no square"? rectangular? or did you some up with a triangular or circular image?

Comment: yes I meant rectangular

Answer (score 0):

Give the `<div>` element a width and a height then add this CSS property,

```
margin: 0px auto;
```

this will align the `<div>` element to centre.

Comment: thanks for your reply but it's not working on wp8, did you try it there?